# FS2: How to get a java.io.InputStream from a fs2.Stream?

Tags: scala, stream, fs2, http4s

Say I have `val fs2Stream: Stream[IO, Byte]` and I need to, for example, call some Java library that requires a `java.io.InputStream`.

I suppose that I'm way too new to FS2, but I cannot seem to find the answer. I've tried to use `fs2.io.toInputStream` and `fs2.io.readInputStream` but I cannot figure out how to provide some of the required parameters. I've scoured the almighty Google for answers, but it seems that the API has changed since most people were last looking for an answer.

How can I go about doing something like the following?

```
def myFunc(data: fs2.Stream[IO, Byte]): InputStream[Byte] = someMagicalFunction(data)
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You probably want something like this:

```
import cats.effect.{ContextShift, IO, Resource}
import java.io.InputStream

def myFunc(data: fs2.Stream[IO, Byte])
          (implicit cs: ContextShift[IO]): Resource[IO, InputStream] =
  data.through(fs2.io.toInputStream).compile.resource.lastOrError
```

Then you can use it like:

```
object JavaApi {
  def foo(is: InputStream): IO[Unit] = ???
}

object Main extends IOApp {
  def data: fs2.Stream[IO, Byte] = ???

  override def run(args: List[String]): IO[ExitCode] =
    myFunc(data).use(JavaApi.foo).as(ExitCode.Success)
}
```

---

Here is an [**Scastie**](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/BalmungSan/xzO9A3RpRriOWTUMLDeCBw/14) with the code running.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. That seems to cause this compile error: 
`Error:(54, 75) no type parameters for method use: (f: java.io.InputStream => G[B])(implicit F: cats.effect.Bracket[G,Throwable]): G[B] exist so that it can be applied to arguments (java.io.InputStream => Unit)
 --- because --
argument expression's type is not compatible with formal parameter type;
 found   : java.io.InputStream => Unit
 required: java.io.InputStream => ?G[?B]
          foo.through(fs2.io.toInputStream).compile.resource.lastOrError.use(JavaApi.foo).as(ExitCode.Success)`. Any thoughts on what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: @foxtrotuniform6969 right a typo, `foo` should have returned **IO[Unit]** instead of **Unit**, sorry. I created a Scastie with a more realistic example. Let me know if you have further problems.

Comment: I was not even aware Scastie existed! Thank you!